# copying the file from ssh

Tags: ssh, scp

I have connected to a esxi server that I created using putty in windows. I want to capture the esxtop output in a csv file to open it with excel. But I can't find the capture.csv file. I looked around and found that I might have to use scp command.

I found this is the general syntax 
scp local_file(s) user@hostname:destination_directory

now what will be the hostname here if I just want to copy capture.csv to a windows drive?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is about copying a file from Linux/UNIX to Windows. To achieve the functionality of `scp` there is a freeware called `WinSCP`, which u can use for copying files. Or create a share in Linux/UNIX side using `Samba` and the share folder can be accessed from Windows.

Comment: Yeah you might be right..thanks for your reply.. But I got what I wanted when i tried scp on linux terminal.. I din't realise I was supposed to try that in cmd prompt in windows and kept trying it in ssh!(and because ssh takes the command, I din't think it was wrong initially)...anyways got the file.

Answer (score 1):

When I output files on an ESX host and need to get them into my windows environment, I just create them on the host itself in a directory on the same data-store as its drives and then connect from windows via WinSCP and FTP them to my local windows desktop.

Sadly, I don't think there is really a better way at this time.